# Concatenar com formato específico

Tags: sql, sql-server

Preciso concatenar duas colunas, uma de ano e uma de mês, mas ainda assim manter um número de caracteres limitado a seis. E quando o mês é menor do que 10 o output trás a concatenação mas apenas com 5 caracteres.

A query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT YEAR(DtFimVigencia) AS Ano,
                MONTH(DtFimVigencia) AS Mês,
                CONVERT(varchar(4), YEAR(DtFimVigencia)) +
                CONVERT(varchar(2), MONTH(DtFimVigencia)) AS AnoMes,
                COUNT(NmContrato) AS Vincendos
FROM Corporativo.VwComercial
WHERE DsRamoWizTOT = 'Residencial'
      AND DtFimVigencia is not null
      AND DsSituacao = 'Emitida'
      AND DsStatus = 'Ativo'
GROUP BY MONTH(DtFimVigencia), YEAR(DtFimVigencia)
ORDER BY YEAR(DtFimVigencia), MONTH(DtFimVigencia) ASC
```

[image: Outputs:]

Precisava que of formato fosse 202001, 202002, etc ... Alguem sabe como proceder?

Comment: Se usou GROUP BY, porque o DISTINCT?

Answer (score 2):

Em vez de montar concatenando, pode usar o [`FORMAT`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/format-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). Por exemplo:

```
SELECT ... FORMAT(DtFimVigencia, 'yyyyMM') AS ...
```